# scipy.stats.scoreatpercentile: need to run import before running code everytime

Tags: python, module, scipy, percentile

I am using scipy's stats.scoreatpercentile in one of my functions. however, whenever I run something which creates an error - which is fixed afterwards - I have to run `from scipy import stats`, otherwise my program starts telling me `pandas.DataFrame do not have the attribute "scoreatpercentile"`. Is that some kind of bug, that I "lose" my imported module or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You might have a naming issue. Do you have multiple variables with the name, say, `stats`? (one of them being the submodule u imported)

Comment: @OneRaynyDay: Yes, you are right, I have a variable called stats! renaming was the solution!

Comment: awesome :) glad I could help

Comment: if you could "move" your comment to an answer, i could mark it as the solution :)

Comment: I'll always take free internet points ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed, it is very likely that you assigned the variable `stats` to another variable, rather than the submodule you imported.

This is why it is considered bad practice to use:

```
from x import y
# do something with y
```

because it *pollutes your namespace*. It is always considered a better idea to use:

```
import x
# do something with x.y
```

If the rationale for using `y` instead of `x.y` is because `x` is a very long name, people use:

```
import reallylongx as x
```

To alleviate the pain of writing extra letters(like `np` instead of `numpy`, `pd` instead of `pandas`, `mpl` instead of `matplotlib`).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(20)
stats.scoreatpercentile(a, 10)
1.9000000000000001
```

Array is numpy type.
That explains why you got pandas.DataFrame do not have the attribute "scoreatpercentile"

Comment: thanks Richard Rublev. That was also my first idea, but the function stats `array_like` and since it works with the import everytime or let's say overwriting, it's what OneRaynyDay figured above